# How to delete the template in Apache IoTDB when prompting that this template already been set and cannot be dropped?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Please tell me how to delete the template used in Apache IoTDB in this situation? I already tried to run `drop device template vehicle` command, but an error occurred: `Msg: 507: Template [vehicle] has been set on MTree, cannot be dropped now`. I wonder if I should write the command in a different way, or if I need to execute any other command before `drop`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first unset the template in Apache IoTDB (`unset device template vehicle` statement), if you already set your template on MTree (put it to use). Then, you can normally execute the `drop` command to delete the template.